# Page does not display correctly in firefox and opera

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on this site and for some reason a couple of the pages do not align correctly in firefox and opera, but work just fine in chrome, IE, and Safari. The basic construction is that I have a div with width, height=100%, within the Div i have a table to separate the sections of the page. The left and right side columns should be filling up the remainder of the width of the screen however in firefox and opera the columns have no width, but in IE, Chrome, and Safari they fill up the remainder. In playing with it if i remove the width parameters on the two middle cells it will line up correctly but this causes text alignment issues in chrome, IE, and Safari. How do I get the columns to fill up the page in all browsers?

Here is a link http://its.truman.edu/International/Meet_A_Student.htm

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Meet A Student</title>
<style type="text/css">
#outer {
    opacity: .5;
}
#img1 {
    opacity: .3;
}
#table1 {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; background-image: url('Pictures/InternationalAppeal-    HomepageColor.jpg'); width:100%; height:100%; clip:auto; overflow:hidden;">
<div style=" position:absolute; height:100%; margin:0px auto">

    <table style="width: 100%; height:100%; border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:#2BA7D0; margin-right:0px; height:100%;" id="outer" >
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; background-image: url('Pictures/Header_New.jpg');width:960px; height:100px" valign="bottom"  >
                <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse:collapse">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:20%"> <a href="/International/Home.htm">
                            <button  type="button" style="color: black;background: #2BA7D0; border:0; height:50px; width:100%"> 
                            <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold"> 
                            Home 
                            </span>
                            </button> 
                        </a></td>
                        <td style="width:20%">  
                            <button  type="button" style="color:white; background:#FA7042; border:0; height:50px; width:100%;">
                            <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold"> 
                            Meet A<br/> Student
                            </span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%"> <a href="/International/Available_Funds.htm"> 
                            <button type="button" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0; background: #2BA7D0; height:50px; width:100%"> 
                            <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold; WORD-WRAP:break-word">
                            Available <br /> Funds
                            </span>
                            </button>
                        </a></td>
                        <td style="width:20%">  <a href="/International/Contact.htm">
                            <button type="button" style="color:black; background:#2BA7D0; border:0; height:50px; width:100%;"> 
                            <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold"> 
                            Contact <br/> Truman
                            </span>
                            </button>
                        </a></td>
                        <td style="width:20%">  <a href="/International/Give.htm">
                            <button type="button" style="color:black; background:#2BA7D0; border:0; height:50px; width:100%;"> 
                            <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold"> 
                            Give
                            </span>
                            </button>
                        </a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="4" style="background-color:#2BA7D0; height:100%;" id="outer">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:480px" >
                <div>
                    <img alt="Wanding Shi" src="Pictures/Wanding Shi.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right:10px" width="258" height="389"/>
                    <div>
                        <p style="font-family:Calibri">
                            <span style="font-size:16pt"> 
                            Wanding Shi
                            </span><br />
                            Senior Business Major<br />
                            <br />
                            Home Country - China<br />
                            <br />
                            &quot;I enjoy the environment at Truman and have 
                            gotten involved in Phi Beta Lambda and the 
                            Bulldog Investment Fund. I am grateful for 
                            the opportunity to get to know students from 
                            different countries while at Truman.&quot;
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </td>
            <td style="width:480px">
                <div>
                    <img alt="Babajide Adio" src="Pictures/Babajide_Adio.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right:10px" width="240" height="389" />
                    <div>
                        <p style="font-family:Calibri">
                            <span style="font-size:16pt">Babajide 
                            Adio</span><br />
                            Senior Biology Major<br />
                            <br />
                            Home Country - Nigeria<br />
                            <br />
                            &quot;At Truman, I have enjoyed great opportunities 
                            to do research with professors since my freshman 
                            year. I have also gotten involved in a lot of 
                            student organizations including honors 
                            organizations, the African Students Association 
                            and Intramural Soccer and Basketball. The 
                            community is very friendly, and it is easy for 
                            every student to find his or her niche. Since 
                            international students don&#39;t qualify for many 
                            scholarships because of citizenship, it would be 
                            wonderful to receive support for international 
                            students.&quot;
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  colspan="2" style="text-align: center; width:20%; background-image:url('Pictures/Footer_New.jpg')" class="style6" >
                <div id="table1"> <table id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:960px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right;font-family:Calibri;margin-bottom:0px; ,margin-top:0px" valign="bottom" > 
                            <p style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:20pt; text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px" >
                                <a href="https://secure.truman.edu/alumni-s/contribution_new.asp" style="text-decoration:none;  color:black">
                                Make a Contribution 
                                <span style="color: #FA7042; font-weight:bolder">
                                TODAY!
                                </span>   
                                <span style="text-decoration: underline">
                                <br/>click here
                                </span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="text-align:right;font-family:Calibri;"> 
                            <span style="font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold; padding-right:40px">
                            Truman State University 
                            </span> <br /> 
                            <span style="font-size:12pt">
                            Office of Advancement | McClain Hall 205&nbsp; <br />
                            &nbsp;100 E. Normal Avenue |Kirksville, MO 65301</span>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="font-family:Calibri;border-left-style: solid;border-left-width: 1px; margin-left:10px; text-align:left"> 
                            <span style="font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;padding-left:50px">
                            <a href="www.truman.edu">
                            www.truman.edu
                            </a>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            <span style="font-size:12pt; margin-left:5px;">
                            (660) 785-4133 or (800) 452-6678
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#2BA7D0; margin-right:0px; height:100%" id="outer" class="style3">
        <br />
        <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're [using the same `id` twice](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fits.truman.edu%2FInternational%2FMeet_A_Student.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  This can be a problem.

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"within the Div i have a table to separate the sections of the page."_  - That's what `div`'s are for.  Have you tried putting `div`'s inside your `div`?

Answer (score 0):

***"for some reason a couple of the pages do not align correctly in firefox and opera"***

You can quikly fix that problem by adjusting this part of your code:

**CHANGE THIS:**

```
<body style="margin: 0; background-image: url('Pictures/InternationalAppeal-    HomepageColor.jpg'); width:100%; height:100%; clip:auto; overflow:hidden;">
<div style=" position:absolute; height:100%; margin:0px auto">
```

**TO:**

```
<body style="margin: 0; background-image: url('Pictures/InternationalAppeal-    HomepageColor.jpg'); width:100%; height:100%; clip:auto; overflow:hidden;">
<div style=" position:relative; height:100%; margin:0px auto">
```

The issue is that if you give `position:absolute;` your are removing the element from the normal document work-flow, thus causing the `margin: 0 auto;` to be meaningless.

---

**What I did** was to change the `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` thus having the `margin:0 auto;` being *"respected"* by the browser.

---

## EDITED

To solve the mentioned issue on your comment, you just need to set the `html` height to `100%;`.

**CSS**

html {
  height: 100%;
}

**Note:** This will tell the browser that the `document` has a `height` of `100%`, thus causing the `body` and `body>div` `height` of `100%` to extend till the end of the `document`.

Comment: If I change it to relative then that creates issues with the length of the page. I want the blue part to extend down to the end of the screen  which works fine when the position is absolute, but when set to relative it will not extend to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Adam Wagenknecht, just added an **edit** to my answer with the solution to that particular issue.

Comment: @Adam Wagenknecht, Glad I could help! If it is solved, please tick the answer as correct to close this question!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following for you main div and body style:

```
<body style="margin: 0; background-image: url('Pictures/InternationalAppeal-       
HomepageColor.jpg'); clip:auto; overflow:hidden;">
<div style="margin:0px auto">.....
```

Ok and for the content: Why do you have so many Divs inside your table? The use of a table defeats the need for using a Div in most cases, so I suggest you take out all the divs in the table. If you want something to behave like a block element such as the images, set display: block or inline-block. 
As for all the dimensions: You defined too many widths and heights. Do not assign the widths in pixels to the td tags, the size of the images will do their job. You can specify their dimensions. Try that and let me know.

Comment: When I remove the position:absolute parameter it prevents the blue from extended to the bottom of the screen(see comment below). 
As for all the div's I did a lot of trial and error to get it to look the way I wanted which included a lot of copying and pasting from different pages where I was trying things, I haven't had a chance to go back and clean it up but this should not be causing my issue.
Without the widths the text does not line up correctly with the images in the center cells like I originally said most of the widths are to contain other objects that are located inside